# Bounded set is contained in a neighbourhood of $0$

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\;\|)$ be a normed vector space over $K\;(\Bbb R\text{ or }\;\Bbb C)$ and let $A\subseteq X$ be non-empty, so I want to prove that:
$$
\text{If }A\text{ is bounded}\Rightarrow\;\forall\text{ neighbourhood }U\text{ of }0\;\exists\;\epsilon>0\;\text{s.t. }aA\subset U\;\forall a\in K\text{  with  } |a|<\epsilon 
$$
So my attempt goes like this:

Let $U$ be any neighbourhood of $0$, so 
$$
\exists r_0>0 \text{ s.t. } B_{r_0}(0)\subset U
$$
Now, let $a\in K$ and let $y\in aA$
$$
\Rightarrow y=ax,\text{  with  }x\in A
$$
So, if $x=0$, taking any $\epsilon>0,$ we get that
$$
\Rightarrow y=0\Rightarrow y\in U
$$
If $x\neq0$, lets take $\epsilon=\frac{r_o}{\|x\|}>0$, so we get that with $|a|<\epsilon$
$$
\Rightarrow\|y\|=\|ax\|=|a|\|x\|<\epsilon\|x\|=r_0\;\Rightarrow y\in B_{r_0}(0)\;\Rightarrow y\in U
$$
Thus, $\forall y\in aA,\; y\in U$. Thereby $aA\subset U$
I don't know what I did wrong or missing, since I didn't the fact that $A$ is bounded. Any comments, suggestions and ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the statement "every bounded set is contained in a neighborhood of 0" is what you are aiming for you're making it way too hard. The set is bounded, so let $M < \infty$ be a strict upper bound on the norm of any element of your set $A$, i.e. $||u|| < M $, $\forall$ $ a \in A$. Then it follows $A \subset B(M,0)$.

Or for your other formulation. Every neighborhood $U$ of $0$ contains a ball about $0$, say $B(r_0,0)$. Use $M$ as a bound for $A$ as before. Then it would follow that $\frac{r_0}{M}A \subset B(r_0,0) \subset U$.

Comment: No, actually "every bounded set is contained in a neighborhood of 0" is what I want to prove, since this could do for proving that then $aA$ is contained in a neighborhood of 0 for an $a$ s.t. $|a|<\epsilon$

Comment: Does my edit help? I am a bit confused as to what you want shown.

Comment: Ok, but I'm getting a bit confused, since I read that if $A$ is bounded that means that there exists $M>0$ and $x_0\in X$ s.t. $\|x-x_0\|<M\;\forall x\in A$. How can you assure $x_0=0$?

Comment: If $A$ is bounded then there is a bound on the norm of any element of $A$, namely there exists $0<M<\infty$ so that $||a||<M$ for all $a \in A$. So clearly $||a-0||=||a||<M$ for all $a \in A$.

Comment: Ok, so provided that $\|x\|<M\;\forall x\in A$, taking $\epsilon=\frac{r_0}{M}$ we get that $\forall y\in aA$ and $\forall a\in K$ with $|a|<\epsilon$
$$
\|y\|=\|ax\|=|a|\|x\|<\epsilon \|x\|<r_0
$$
and thus $aA\subset U$

Comment: Sorry if the question seems dummy but where can I read about that if $A$ is bounded then there is a bound on the norm?, since I only knew the other one with $\|x-x_0\|$

Comment: The two are equivalent, you should be able to show it using the triangle inequality. Conceptually, if everything is within a finite distance of a point, they are within a finite distance of 0, namely they are at worst the sum of the distance to the point and the distance from the point to 0.

Comment: Suppose that by the statement that the set $A$ is bounded you mean that there is an $x_0$ and an $M$ such that if $x\in A$ then $\Vert x-x_0\Vert\le M$. By the triangle inequality it follows that if $x\in A$ then $\Vert x \Vert=\Vert x_0+(x-x_0)\Vert\le \Vert x_0\Vert+\Vert x-x_0\Vert\le\Vert x_0\Vert + M$. So you have a ball centered at 0 containing $A$.

Comment: Ok, I see it know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have $A$ bounded.

Suppose $\|x\| < B$ for all $x \in A$.

If $U$ is a neighbourhood of $0$ then  $B(0,r) \subset U$ for some $r$.

Now let $\epsilon= { r \over B}$, and suppose $|a| < \epsilon$.

If $ax = 0$, then it is clear that $ax \in B(0,r)$, so suppose
$ax \neq 0$.

Then if $x \in B$, we have
$\|ax\| =|a| \|x\| < \epsilon \|x\| =r$ and so $ax \in B(0,r)$.

**Note**: If $A$ is unbounded, then $A \not\subset B(0,r)$ for all $r$.